# Php array String

Tags: php, array

Hola buenas tengo este código en php para visualizar los valores del array pero me sale un error de Array to string conversion y no se porque.

Codigo:

```
<?php   
    echo "<h3>Diferentes formas de array</h3>";
    echo "Funcion array()";
    $colores = array(
                0=>'azul',
                1=>'rojo',
                2=>'verde');
    echo "Resultado de la funcion es: ".$colores;
    $colores2 = array("azul","rojo","verde");
    echo "Valor del array: ".$colores2;
?>
```

Comment: Estas tratando de llamarlo como si fuese una cadena, pero en realidad lo que tienes es un array como el error te lo dice, en php para imprimirlo es elemento por elemento o en su caso utilizar alguna función de php para poder visualizar todo el contenido del array, como por ejemplo  `implode` o un `json_encode`, etc.

Comment: También lo puedes leer iterando dentro de un bucle: `foreach ($colores as $row){echo $row."<br />";}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje lo dice todo: **no puedes convertir un *arreglo* en una cadena**.

Para ello, puedes usar la función [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)

> **implode( )**
>   `string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )`
>   `string implode ( array $pieces )`
>   
>   Une elementos de un array en un string con glue (pegamento).

En tu caso:

```
<?php   
  echo "<h3>Diferentes formas de array</h3>";
  echo "Funcion array()";
  $colores = array(
               0=>'azul',
               1=>'rojo',
               2=>'verde');

  echo "Resultado de la funcion es: ".implode( $colores);
  $colores2 = array("azul","rojo","verde");
  echo "Valor del array: ".implode( $colores2 );
?>
```